# Multiple OR in php if() not seeming to respond properly. Tested array values and all. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

I am running a very simple if statement which works perfect until I add the two additional || (or) operators.

Here is my code:

```
if ($planDetails['Company']['name'] != 'company1'
|| $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name'] != 'pd-name1' 
|| $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name'] != 'pd-name2') { echo "TEST"; }
```

**I've checked my array data and table values to ensure they are precise in the names etc**.. And this is not kicking. What am I doing wrong? When I remove the additional 2 || options, the first argument works fine, so I know my logic is correct.

What in the name am I doing wrong here. Someone please set me straight!

Comment: post a `var_dump($planDetails);`

Comment: Matt, my dump is much too large to sensibly post here, but I already checked that. The array contains the values I need and I am echoing them out simply by: echo $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name']; gets me the correct value on the requested page.

Comment: "this is not kicking" - Which means? I interpreted that as "it does not print out `TEST`", which is probably not what you meant.

Comment: Yes, Eric I meant it's not working as intended. The "TEST" should only echo if no matches are found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ors should be ands. The expression `a != 1 || a != 2` is always true because whatever the value of a is, one or the other of the expressions will be true, so the final result will be true.

To fix, change `||` to `&&`.

I guess you made this mistake because you started with this expression and wanted to invert it:

```
if ($planDetails['Company']['name'] == 'company1'
|| $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name'] == 'pd-name1' 
|| $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name'] == 'pd-name2')
```

The simplest way to invert this expressions is as follows:

```
if (!($planDetails['Company']['name'] == 'company1'
|| $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name'] == 'pd-name1' 
|| $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name'] == 'pd-name2'))
```

Using this method, you don't need to do any complex boolean logic in your head to see that it works - it's just a simple negation of what you already know. Note that this is *not* the same as inverting the `==` to `!=` individually. See [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Well, what I read here is:

```
If $variable is not equal to A Or $variable is not equal to B
Then echo "TEST"
```

Since `$variable` cannot be equal to both A and B at the same time, it will *always* print "TEST".

Of course, the above refers to the last two conditions in your `if`.

Comment: +1: It becomes clearer if you apply [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and think of the statement as: `If NOT($variable = A AND $variable = B)`. Then it's obvious that $variable cannot be both A and B simultaneously.

Comment: I'm getting a taste of this logic now. This really threw me a left curve as I now see how wrong I was. Thanks for the added clarification.

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
NOT (P AND Q) = (NOT P) OR (NOT Q)
NOT (P OR Q) = (NOT P) AND (NOT Q)
```

You have:

```
(NOT P) OR (NOT Q) OR (NOT R)
```

Which is the same as:

```
NOT (P AND Q) OR (NOT R) => 
NOT (P AND Q AND R)
```

Therefore, P, Q, R must all be **false** to print "TEST".  If one of them is **true** then you will not print "TEST".

I believe you want:

```
NOT (P OR Q OR R)
```

Which would be:

```
(NOT P) AND (NOT Q) AND (NOT R)
```

OR

```
if (!($planDetails['Company']['name'] == 'company1'
|| $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name'] == 'pd-name1' 
|| $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name'] == 'pd-name2'))
{ 
    echo "TEST"; 
}
```

AKA

```
if ($planDetails['Company']['name'] != 'company1'
&& $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name'] != 'pd-name1' 
&& $planDetails['PlanDetail']['name'] != 'pd-name2')
{ 
    echo "TEST"; 
}
```

Comment: wow, that took me too long to type... it appears others have also posted similar answers

Comment: Dan, thanks very much for the added clarification. I see exactly what you are describing. My logic was extremely flawed.

Comment: Yes, that's why I put it first.  It "reads" easier.  For the fun of it, you could have put them in an array and do a contains (but worse performance): http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php