# Visual Basic Do While Loop with several OR's

Tags: while-loop, console-application, visual-studio-2013, do-while, do-loops

Ok, so I'm new to Visual Basic, not to others. I have an assignment for college and this is probably ahead of the curve, but I decided to do some automated error checking in the program we're writing for an assignment. We haven't covered loops yet, but my "Don't trust the user to not input something they're not supposed to" sense is itching badly. Here's my code:

```
    Console.WriteLine("What is your marital status?")
    Console.Write("Enter (m)arried, (s)ingle, (d)ivorced, (w)idowed: ")
    maritalStatus = Console.ReadLine()
    Do While maritalStatus IsNot "m" Or maritalStatus IsNot "s" Or maritalStatus IsNot "d" Or maritalStatus IsNot "w"
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid marital status.")
        Console.Write("Enter (m)arried, (s)ingle, (d)ivorced, (w)idowed: ")
        maritalStatus = Console.ReadLine()
    Loop
    Console.Clear()
```

The good news is if you input anything other that m, s, d, or w it loops back and tells you to enter a valid one. The bad news is it does that even if you put in m, s, d, or w.

My googling patience is growing thin. Any help offered?

Comment: Try "and" instead of "or".

Comment: By the way, changing the IsNot to <> operators doesn't do it either.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch That worked. I think I've been working too long on too little sleep... Do that as the answer and I'll mark it as so

Comment: so if it's not `m` then it will loop. if it's not `s` then it will loop. if it's not `d` then it will loop.  if it's not `w` then it will loop.... if it IS `s` then it's not `m`... obviously to that logic, it will loop

Comment: It's a common problem.  "And/Or" in normal English usage don't exactly map straight to programming/mathematics.  :-)

Comment: Different programming langue, but [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198895/multiple-or-in-php-if-not-seeming-to-respond-properly-tested-array-values-and/5199123#5199123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "and" instead of "or".

Comment: Will accept when eligible too. Apparently this was answered too soon. Said in 9 minutes

Comment: I think 9 minutes is up? eh?

Comment: Sorry it took so long, slipped my mind (all 9 months worth... had twins since then)